# Числа и запятые в валидаторе PySide

Tags: python, python-3.x, gui, pyqt, pyside2

В *PySide2* я сделал валидатор, чтобы можно было вводить только цифры.

Как теперь еще добавить в валидатор, чтобы помимо цифр я мог вводить `запятые`?

```
    self.onlyInt = QtGui.QIntValidator()
    self.spectras_list = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.spectras_list.setFixedWidth(200)
    self.spectras_list.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
```

Comment: QDoubleValidator?

Comment: Использовать QDoubleValidator

Comment: Он для чисел с плавающей точкой. А мне нужно вводить числа типа int просто через запятую

Comment: Вы можете написать валидатор на основе регулярного выражения. См. QRegExpValidator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс `QRegExpValidator` используется для проверки строки на соответствие регулярному выражению.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregexpvalidator.html#details

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Напишите здесь свой текст")
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit() #TextEdit()
        
        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.lineEdit) 
        self.grid.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        
        self.setValidation()   

    def setValidation(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("setValidator->[0-9 ,]+")
 
        reg_ex = QRegExp("[0-9 ,]+")
        label_validator = QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, self.lineEdit)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(label_validator)    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Hello QRegExpValidator")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь !